# Should there be a Romance-languages tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Just what the title says. Does it make sense to create [romance-languages](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romance-languages)?

From time to time we get questions like [Why did "cattus" replace Latin "feles"?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/8925/why-did-cattus-replace-latin-feles) asking about the specifics of the evolution of Latin to modern languages.

I'm not sure all those fall under [medieval-latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medieval-latin) and at times it feels unfit to tag them in a specific language (in the example, it would be [spanish](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spanish),) even if the OP gives examples in the given language. I also think [language-evolution](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-evolution) is a little too broad for this purpose.

Would it be too specific? Is there a criterion for tags's specificity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a criterion for tags's specificity?

If the community wants a tag, we can have it.
That's all there is to it, really.

We are such a small community that if anyone feels like creating a new tag, you can just go ahead and add it to a question.
[Anyone with at least 150 reputation can create a tag.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)

If there are disagreements, they can be sorted out later.
Tags can be renamed, merged, blacklisted, synonymized, and maybe there are some other actions I forget.
Bigger SE communities seem to have a policy that a new tag needs to be proposed and approved on meta, but I don't think we need that.
Bad tag ideas are so rare that we have no reason to prepare for them.
That said, it's never wrong to bring something up on meta.

> Does it make sense to create [romance-languages](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romance-languages)?

It does!
Feel free to go ahead and add it to any appropriate questions.

It'd be nice to have a use guidance (tag wiki excerpt) to describe the tag.
It is mostly self-explanatory, but it could mention related tags like [language-evolution](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-evolution), [medieval-latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medieval-latin), and tags for individual Romance languages.
It often makes sense to use a number of these tags together, and in the case of the example question you cite I'd also consider adding [language-evolution](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-evolution).

Comment: By "in this case" in your last sentence you mean the question I linked as example?

Comment: @Rafael I do, and I edited for clarity.